# How many four-digit integers are there that contain exactly one $8$?

Tags: combinatorics

My book gives:

$$1 \times 9 \times 9 \times 9 + 3 \times 8 \times 9 \times 9 = 2673$$ integers

I don't understand where the $3$ comes from in the second part.

I understand the first part, $1 \times 9 \times 9 \times 9$. I believe it's saying we have $1$ choice to put $8$ in the beginning, $9$ choices of $\{0\} + \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9\}$ for the remaining three positions.

Comment: There are three places to put the $8$, if you exclude the first digit which has to be treated separately.

Comment: Usually, the first digit is assumed to be non-zero.

Comment: @lulu I see. So we use 3 to put 8 in one of the three spots, which isn't the first. That means the 8 we multiply 3 by can be our first digit, which can only be from {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9}, and the other two 9's we multiply by can be from {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9}?

Comment: Yes, you've got it.

Answer (score 2):

You made a good start. Indeed, if you fix the first spot as $8$, the second, third and fourth spot can be filled with any digit in $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9\}$, hence you have $9^3$ possible choices.

It remains to count how many number you could have when the first spot is not $8$. Notice that, as Peter suggests above, usually the first digit is supposed to be not zero. 
Fix the second spot to be $8$. Then you have only $8$ possible choices for the first digit, infact you can choose any number in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9\}$. The third and fourth spot can be filled with any number different to $8$, that is any number in $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9\}$. Thus you have $8\times 9^2$ choices fixing the second spot to be $8$. The same reasoning can be done also when you fix the third spot to be $8$ and when you fix the fourth spot to be $8$. In other words, when the first spot in not $8$ you have $8\times 9^2 + 8\times 9^2+8\times 9^2=3\times 8\times 9^2$ possible choices.

Hence the total amount is $9^3+3\times 8\times 9^2$ numbers.